# Dealing with a chmod gone wrong

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I could use some advice to fix an accidentally broken system. My colleague shot himself in the foot with Linux and now at least his Docker doesn't work properly anymore, but god knows what other issues will come up later.

In a dev project he executed `sudo chmod -R 755 /var` where he used `/var` instead of the local `var` folder. He doesn't really understand Linux, and now it's my job to fix it :-(

Now when I start docker containers it seems successful, but `docker ps` doesn't list them and I cannot enter them with `docker exec` because it says that they're not running.

The docker problems are probably only the first symptoms. Does anyone have any advice on what I could do? How bad is this?

System is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: may be better off getting this moved to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the kind of "oops" that'd make me first yell at the responsible party, and have them reinstall the entire system. Fixing permissions for individual files and folders is often more tedious if the mistake was done close to the root.